# Asp.Net custom validation control not showing error messages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, validation

The following code is used to validate when form submit button is hit, but I am not getting the wanted result back.

It should display the error messages but they are not being displayed what am I doing wrong?

The custom validator validates passwords,  it should change the error message based on the which errors occur:

1. Password is blank
2. Password is invalid
3. Passwords do not match

Only one error should show at a time so I wrote this custom validtor in .ascx.cs:

```
    protected void cvPasswordValidation_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {

        bool IsPasswordBlank = false;
        bool IsPasswordValid = false;

        cvPasswordValidation.IsValid = false;

        // If password is blank then IsValid is false, show blank password errors.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Value))
        {

            //args.IsValid = false;
            IsPasswordBlank = true;
            //Show blank password error depending on which box is empty.
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text))
            {
                cvPasswordValidation.ErrorMessage = "You must enter password";
            }
            else
            {
                cvPasswordValidation.ErrorMessage = "You must confirm password";
            }
            cvPasswordValidation.IsValid = false;

        }
        else
        {
            cvPasswordValidation.IsValid = true;
        }

        // If password is not valid format then IsValid is false, show invalid format errors.
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(args.Value, RegexHelper.ValidPassword)) 
        {

            IsPasswordValid = true;
            //Show invalid format errors, if password is not blank
            if (IsPasswordBlank == false)
            {
                cvPasswordValidation.ErrorMessage = "<b>Current password</b> not in correct format. Your password must contain 6 - 12 characters with a combination of numbers and letters.";
            }
            cvPasswordValidation.IsValid = false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            cvPasswordValidation.IsValid = true; 
        } 

        // If passwords do not match then IsValid is false, show do not match errors.
        bool areEqual = String.Equals(txtPassword.Text, txtConfirmPassword.Text, StringComparison.Ordinal);

        if (areEqual == false)
        {

            //Show do not match errors is password is not blank and is not invalid format
            if (IsPasswordBlank == false && IsPasswordValid == false)
            {
                cvPasswordValidation.ErrorMessage = "Your passwords do not match.";
            }
            cvPasswordValidation.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cvPasswordValidation.IsValid = true;
        }

    }
```

and the .ascx:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" MaxLength="12" autocomplete="off" TextMode="Password" ValidationGroup="vgOnlineDetails"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvPasswordValidation"
                 runat="server"
                 display="Dynamic"
                 OnServerValidate="cvPasswordValidation_ServerValidate"
                 ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                 ValidationGroup="vgOnlineDetails">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: What is your problem? Does the validator not work, please explain what happens/goes wrong and also post the markup that actually uses the validator.

Comment: The error messages do not get displayed, I am not to sure on how to exactly debug validators would like to learn I am just getting the markup.

Comment: once you set `cvPasswordValidation.IsValid = false;` on any condition, couldn't you `return` from the handler?

Comment: No I couldn't return from the handler, it's wierd don't know why trying to debug now but seeing nothing.

Comment: My bad Knvn I just got whant you meant the `return` isn't working for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [ValidateEmptyText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext.aspx) = true to validate empty fields.

Comment: This seems to be the answer, it was not validating empty text fields, when I type something in the validation seems to work fine :D. Just got to test with project if everything checks out will accept answer :).

Comment: Accepted answer because it solved main issue that I was discussing of errors not being shown. Should read Igor Blinnikov answer if you still do not recieve error messages because IsValid is always true.

Answer (score 1):

You shoul use `return` after assignment to IsValid property. Condider situation when you do not specify password at all. If you do not specify `return` after assignment all three `if` statements will be executed. In last `if` `areEqual` variable will be `true` because two empty strings are equal and `cvPasswordValidation.IsValid = true;` will be executed. In this case your text boxes will be valid.

Comment: I finally get what you mean, just type `Return;` quite literally after the `args.IsValid = false; Return;` Still giving me the same issue.